# Flutter: How to position a text in front of background?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i'm learning Flutter now. And i have some problem that my text "welcome" is not in front of the background but it . How can i fix it? I think it causes of container but i don't know how to order it correctly. Sorry for my bad code format.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Login',
      home: Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 11, 0, 0),
              child: Text('Welcome', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 80, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
        Container(
        color: Colors.orangeAccent[100],
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 420,
        height: 700,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: MyPainter(), 
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.15),
            child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
              children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                  text: '    JUST BECAUSE YOU\n',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[700], fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ]
      )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my code for customPainter.

```
class MyPainter extends CustomPainter{
  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    //final width = size.width;

    Path pigPath = Path();
    Path ovalPath = Path();


    pigPath.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.417);
    pigPath.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.25, size.height * 0.6,
        size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.37);
    pigPath.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.7, size.height * 0.23,
        size.width * 1.0, size.height * 0.2);
    pigPath.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    pigPath.lineTo(0, size.height);
    paint.color = Colors.cyan[100];
    canvas.drawPath(pigPath, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;

}
```

[This is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGaeD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Login',
      home: Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[

        Container(
        color: Colors.orangeAccent[100],
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 420,
        height: 700,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: MyPainter(), 
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.15),
            child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
              children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                  text: '    JUST BECAUSE YOU\n',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[700], fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
          ),
        ),
      ),
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 11, 0, 0),
              child: Text('Welcome', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 80, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ]
      )
      )
    );
  }
}
```